# Using ifelse statement when concatenating elements of a date variable

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am attempting to use two ifelse statements to create a new date variable that makes a series of assumptions to fill in the gaps of an existing date variable. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
  id EffectiveDate EffectiveYear ED_NA EY_NA NewEffectiveDate
1  a    1972-10-05          1972 FALSE FALSE       1972-10-05
2  a          <NA>          1985  TRUE FALSE       1985-01-01
3  a    1988-11-12          1988 FALSE FALSE       1988-11-12
4  b    2011-09-05          2011 FALSE FALSE       2011-09-05
5  b          <NA>            NA  TRUE  TRUE       2011-09-05
6  b          <NA>          2012  TRUE FALSE       2012-01-01
7  c    2012-11-11          2012 FALSE FALSE       2012-11-11
8  c    2013-05-15          2013 FALSE FALSE       2013-05-15
```

quick code for id:EY_NA =

```
id <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c")
EffectiveDate <- c("1972-10-05",NA,"1988-11-12","2011-09-05",NA,NA,"2012-11-11","2013-05-15")
EffectiveYear <- c(1972,1985,1988,2011,NA,2012,2012,2013)
tdat <- data.frame(id, EffectiveDate, EffectiveYear)
tdat$ED_NA <- is.na(tdat$EffectiveDate)
tdat$EY_NA <- is.na(tdat$EffectiveYear)
```

What I'm trying to create in this example is the "NewEffectiveDate" variable. In plain English, what I want is, where EffectiveDate data are missing BUT EffectiveYear data are not missing, assume NewEffectiveDate is equal to January 1 of the EffectiveYear. If EffectiveDate AND EffectiveYear data are missing, assume the prior observation's EffectiveDate. Last, of course, if EffectiveDate data are not missing, select EffectiveDate.

Here is the latest code I used to attempt to solve the problem:

```
tdat %>% mutate(NewEffectiveDate = ifelse(ED_NA == 1 & EY_NA == 0,
  as.Date(paste(EffectiveYear, 1, 1, sep="-")),
  ifelse(ED_NA == 1 & EY_NA == 1), 
  as.Date(lag(EffectiveDate)),
  EffectiveDate
))
```

When I try this particular code, I get an error message that reads: Error: unused arguments (as.Date(c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 4)), c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 4, 5))

I searched for similar questions with queries like "ifelse concatenate date" and some variations thereof, but haven't found anything that seems to apply to this particular problem.

I am very new to R (and CLIs, for that matter), so I apologize in advance if I'm overlooking a perfectly obvious solution. The transition from Excel to R has been interesting, but often painful when it comes to doing what seem like relatively straightforward tasks (though the dplyr package has been tremendously helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c")
EffectiveDate <- c("1972-10-05",NA,"1988-11-12","2011-09-05",NA,NA,"2012-11-11","2013-05-15")
EffectiveYear <- c(1972,1985,1988,2011,NA,2012,2012,2013)
tdat <- data.frame(id, EffectiveDate, EffectiveYear,
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(zoo)
tdat %>% 
  mutate(NewEffectiveDate = ifelse(!is.na(EffectiveDate),
                                   EffectiveDate,
                                   ifelse(is.na(EffectiveDate) & !is.na(EffectiveYear),
                                          paste0(EffectiveYear, "-01-01"),
                                          NA)),
         NewEffecitveDate = na.locf(NewEffectiveDate))
```

This should give you what you need.  I recommend using `na.locf` (last one carried forward) from the `zoo` package rather than trying to deal with the previous date issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
tdat$EffectiveDate <- as.Date(tdat$EffectiveDate)

tdat %>% mutate(NewEffectiveDate = as.Date(
    ifelse(!is.na(EffectiveDate), EffectiveDate,
           ifelse(!is.na(EffectiveYear), as.Date(paste(EffectiveYear, 1, 1, sep="-")),
                  lag(EffectiveDate)))
)) -> res

res
#   id EffectiveDate EffectiveYear NewEffectiveDate
# 1  a    1972-10-05          1972       1972-10-05
# 2  a          <NA>          1985       1985-01-01
# 3  a    1988-11-12          1988       1988-11-12
# 4  b    2011-09-05          2011       2011-09-05
# 5  b          <NA>            NA       2011-09-05
# 6  b          <NA>          2012       2012-01-01
# 7  c    2012-11-11          2012       2012-11-11
# 8  c    2013-05-15          2013       2013-05-15
```

Comment: Many thanks. This solution worked as well. One quick follow up question though: why the use of curly brackets in this formula? I think you get to the same answer without them.

Comment: @wdf1088 removed them, they just helped get the proper indent (ess formatting)

Comment: OK. I thought as much. Slightly off topic, but is there a standard or preferred format when it comes to code like this, or coding in general? I mentioned this already in my question post, but I'm really quite new to all of this, and I'm trying to gather as many reference materials as possible. I sincerely welcome any suggestions you might have, especially if it helps to make my code more readable.

Comment: @wdf1088 there are at least a few formats people seem to use.  You will see a lot of code with two space indents (like the answer above), coming from RStudio default formatting.  4 spaces is also common (like mine) coming from ESS (emacs) formatting.  I think in general, try to use functions that help readability like `with`.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with your `ifelse` block you closed the bracket for the second block early and didn't give a `yes` or `no` argument and you gave an extra argument to the first `ifelse` block.

This should work:

```
tdat %>% mutate(NewEffectiveDate = ifelse(ED_NA == 1 & EY_NA == 0,
  as.Date(paste(EffectiveYear, 1, 1, sep="-")),
  ifelse(ED_NA == 1 & EY_NA == 1, 
  as.Date(lag(EffectiveDate))),
  EffectiveDate))
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a good catch. I think though there's also a problem in your suggested code. The third ")" on the fourth line should be moved to the end of the fifth line in order to capture the arguments of the ifelse statements correctly. However, when I do this, I get a different error message. This one now reads: Error: 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: The `origin` that needs to supplied is for the mutate function I think. You need to specify the original column that needs to be "mutated" in the function.